# Line arrow size is small in jsxgraph

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

In latest nightly build of jsxgraph the size of line arrow is very small. Tried making arrow using firstArrow and lastArrow in line and creating arrow from points. Both results the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for point this out. Actually, since v0.99.7 it is possible to configure the type and size of the arrow heads by setting the attributes `lastArrow` or `firstArrow` to an object instead of a boolean. Example:

```
lastArrow: {
    type: 1,
    highlightSize: 6,
    size: 6
}
```

Upto now, the arrow element had the attribute `lastArrow:true` hard coded and internally used the hard coded value `size == 3`. The following changes are in the sources now:

- The above example is the default for arrow elements
- `size == 6` is taken for the case `lastArrow == true`

It will be available in today's nightly build.